# Class Not Updating Variables passed byref

Tags: vb.net, variables, byref

I have a class in vb.net defined as public class A

class A is created on Load and gets called once per program loop

The constructor for class A includes the argument (byref Value as long)

I have a global variable called varB that is passed to class A on creation.

now why when varB is altered during the program loop, the change is not reflected within the class?

Answer (score 2):

If only that was so simple... ByRef only works inside the sub/function you called, to modifiy the variable you 'send', and after returning from that sub/function, no more changes are made.

```
Public Class ClassOne
    Public ValuefromClassOne As Integer
    Public Sub ChangeAValue(ByRef AValue As Integer)
        AValue = 12   ' This will modifiy the variable
        ValuefromClassOne = AValue   ' this will ONLY put 12 inside ValueFromClassOne
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class ClassTwo
    Public ValueFromClassTwo As Integer
    Public Sub CallToClassOne()
        ChangeAValue(ValueFromClassTwo)    ' this will ONLY put 12 into ValueFromClassTwo
        ValueFromClassTwo = 25    ' this will have effect only on ValueFromClassTwo - no link
    End Sub
End Class
```

So if you want to have the value, you have to use an object (define new Class)

```
Public Class IntegerHolder
    Public Property AnInteger As Integer
End Class

Public Class ClassOne
    Public ValuefromClassOne As IntegerHolder
    Public Sub ChangeAValue(ByVal AValue As IntegerHolder)
        AValue.AnInteger = 12   ' This will modifiy the variable
        ValueFromClassOne.AnInteger = AValue.AnInteger   ' this will ONLY put 12 inside ValueFromClassOne
        ' !!!!! BUT with this : !!!!
        ValueFromClassOne = AValue
        ' Now you hold a copy of the variable given in argument of ChangeAValue 
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class ClassTwo
    Public ValueFromClassTwo As New IntegerHolder
    Public Sub CallToClassOne()
        ChangeAValue(ValueFromClassTwo)    ' this will ONLY put 12 into ValueFromClassTwo
        ValueFromClassTwo.AnInteger = 25    ' this will have effect on
        ' ValueFromClassTwo  AND  ValuefromClassOne
    End Sub
End Class
```

But notice that a change on ValueFromClassTwo will be reflected, but not
notified : use a public shared event in ClassTwo to notify / Add an event
 Handler in ClassOne to get notified.